# How to see number of NFS service workers on a Mac

Tags: mac, nfs

How do I see how many `nfsd` service workers are running on my Mac?

---

### Context

I'm working with a Vagrant-environment that is quite slow. I can see that the network interface is quite burdened, from looking at `tcpdump -i any port not 22` inside the VM. And looking at [bpytop](https://github.com/aristocratos/bpytop) inside the box as well.

I can read from these two articles:

- [Optimizing Your NFS Filesystem](https://www.admin-magazine.com/HPC/Articles/Useful-NFS-Options-for-Tuning-and-Management)
- [Tuning NFS for better performance](https://www.techrepublic.com/blog/linux-and-open-source/tuning-nfs-for-better-performance/)

... that NFS can be improved by changing the amount of service workers that the `nfsd`-daemon is running. But their guides on how to do this, is Unix-specific - and I'm on a Mac.

And I'm struggle to figure out, how I see how many service workers I have running.

---

### Solution attempts

- I tried looking at `nfsstat`, but couldn't really see it there.
- I tried making `nfsstat` run every second with this command: `while true; do nfsstat; echo " \n\n --------- \n\n $(date '+%H:%M:%S') \n\n"; sleep 1; done` - to see if I could spot any significant change somewhere there.
- I looked at `/etc/nfs.conf` but that's empty (disregarding the comment in the top).
- I looked at `/etc/exports/` as well, but that just lists the mounted folders.
- I tried looking at `ps aux | egrep "nfs|PID"`, but I can't really see anything of significance there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was found by exploring the `nfsd` command in the terminal.

I could see the amount by writing: `nfsd status`.

---

### How to change it

By writing: `man nfsd` I could see that I could add a `-n` flag, which made it possible to specify the amount of threads to start (default was 8). But if I wrote:

```
sudo nfsd stop
```

And then

```
sudo nfsd start -n 16
```

And then

```
nfsd status
```

... The it still showed 8 threads.

I tried a buuuunch of different things.

The solution was found by writing: `man nfs.conf`, where I could see that I could add this line:

```
nfs.server.nfsd_threads=16
```

to `/etc/nfs.conf`.

After I did that, I wrote: `sudo nfsd restart` and BAM! 16 threads running. Booh-yah!